# Why did the graboid destroy Burt's truck?

Tags: movie, tremors

In *Tremors*, after Burt and Heather kill the second graboid, they climb to their roof. Later, Val radios them with a plan to hop in their truck and get some help from Bixby, as they have the last truck in town that can make it.

Conveniently for the plot, a graboid destroys their truck at this moment.

**Why did it do that?**

This graboid was away when the truck arrived, so it couldn't know this inanimate object was a car. Nobody was in the truck at this time, and the engine seems shut down, so it couldn't be making noises. Every other time a creature attacks a vehicle during the movie, someone was inside / on it.

In Wikia's Burt Gummer's page, it says that :

> "[...] the plan is made moot when the creatures start tearing the town
>   apart from the below and eat the tires on their cars."

... But I was under the impression that the graboids were trying to feel the foundations of the buildings on which the characters were standing, and not randomly destroying objects on the ground.

So, is there a in-universe explanation as to why the graboid decide to destroy Burt's and Heather's truck?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The graboids were investigating the foundations of Burt & Heather's compound when they went ***under*** their truck. The alarm went off and the noise/vibration inspired the graboids to suck it under the ground as a potential food source.

Per the [screenplay](https://sfy.ru/?script=tremors)

> **HEATHER:** *We're with you, Val.  We'll come get everybody.  Just hang on tight.*
>
> **[The truck's security alarm starts BOOPING!  Burt and Heather stare
>   down helplessly as the noisy truck is furiously attacked by the
>   frenzied creatures.  Dust flies as metal rips and tires shred.**]
>
> [**Val Earl and Miguel listen in disbelief to the distant truck alarm. 
>   It finally sputters and dies.**]
>
> **HEATHER** (V.O.): *Val, we're going to have to forget about the truck...*
>
> **VAL** (into CB): *Yeah, Heather, we got you.*

Comment: Ah! I haven't thought about it this way! This seeems to be the answer I was looking for! Will wait a few days before accepting.